# In "Elektra: Assassin" where does the milk of The Beast come from?

Tags: marvel

In the great comic series *Elektra: Assassin* by Frank Miller and Bill Sienkiewicz, The Beast - an antichrist apocalyptic entity - with the help of The Hand controls people by forcing them to drink a liquid substance they call "milk", which induces them to serve The Beast.

Ken Wind, the presidential candidate, attempts to make agent Garret drink the Beast's milk, which Garret refers to as having the smell of rancid mayonnaise (that scene sticks to your head, if you ever smelled bad milk).

So, I wonder: where does the milk come from? Is it from the body of The Beast itself, or is it some substance that The Hand manages to manufacture?

Comment: One of the reviews [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Elektra-Assassin-Frank-Miller/dp/0785163549) says that it's the Beast's semen.

Comment: Geeez... I wonder where did he took that from? "Its a comic celebrating and simultaneously poking fun at the over-sexualization of women, Elektra in particular." Not that it doesn't make sense, it's a grim perspective, but it fits the overall character profile of being abused and fighting back abuse.

Comment: Beast is best!™